# Can Serde deserialize JSON to one of a set of types depending on the value of a field?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a group of different messages that come in as JSON and can be distinguished based on a single field, but then each variant has a different collection of secondary fields:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageOne {
    ///op will always be "one"
    op: String,
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageTwo {
    ///op will always be "two"
    op: String,
    a: f64,
    b: i64,
}
```

The different message types are routed to different processing functions (e.g. `process_message_one`, `process_message_two`, etc). Is there an elegant or idiomatic way to automatically select the correct message sub-type? Currently I've defined a generic message:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageGeneric {
    op: String,
}
```

then parse the incoming JSON into the `MessageGeneric`, read the `op` field and then deserialize again, matching on `op` to select the correct message type. Full example:

```
#![allow(unused)]

extern crate serde; // 1.0.78
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.27

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageGeneric {
    op: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageOne {
    ///op will always be "one"
    op: String,
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageTwo {
    ///op will always be "two"
    op: String,
    a: f64,
    b: f64,
}

fn process_message_one(m: &MessageOne) {
    println!("Processing a MessageOne: {:?}", m);
}

fn process_message_two(m: &MessageTwo) {
    println!("Processing a MessageTwo: {:?}", m);
}



fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
        "op": "one",
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 2.0
    }"#;

    let z: MessageGeneric = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();

    match z.op.as_ref() {
        "one" => {
            let zp: MessageOne = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
            process_message_one(&zp);
        },
        "two" => {
            let zp: MessageTwo = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
            process_message_two(&zp);
        },
        _ => println!("Unknown Message Type")

    }

}
```

I've seen [Serde's enum representations](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) but it was unclear to me if/how that would be applied in this case. The messages coming in are defined by an external API, so I can't control their content beyond knowing what the variants are.

Answer (score 17):

There is no point to keep "one" or "two" in your structure `MessageOne` and `MessageTwo`: if you have constructed this structure you already know if it is message one or message two.

```
extern crate serde; // 1.0.78
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.27

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "op")]
enum Message {
    #[serde(rename = "one")]
    One { x: f64, y: f64 },
    #[serde(rename = "two")]
    Two { a: f64, b: f64 },
}

fn process_message(message: &Message) {
    println!("Processing a : {:?}", message);
}

use serde_json::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let data = r#"{
        "op": "one",
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 2.0
    }"#;

    let message: Message = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
    process_message(&message);

    let data = r#"{
        "op": "two",
        "a": 1.0,
        "b": 2.0
    }"#;

    let message: Message = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
    process_message(&message);

    let data = r#"{
        "op": "42",
        "i": 1.0,
        "j": 2.0
    }"#;

    let message: Message = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
    process_message(&message);
    Ok(())
}
```

```
Standard Output
Processing a : One { x: 1.0, y: 2.0 }
Processing a : Two { a: 1.0, b: 2.0 }

Standard Error
Error: Error("unknown variant `42`, expected `one` or `two`", line: 2, column: 18)
```

Comment: What if the `MessageOne`, `MessageTwo`, etc structs are defined in a third-party crate with the `op` field? Is it still possible to create an `enum` that collects them together and then parses to the correct one?

Comment: @JoshAdel I don't understand your problem,  just create an untagged enum, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=d97b9f54b0cfaf09fced32cde94de0a3. But your question doesn't include your real problem. For exemple, if these structures are defined somewhere else why do they derive `Serialize` and `Deserialize` ? If you still have problem please do another question that describe exactly your case or come to rust chat.