# How to deserialize JSON where the types of the values are specified in another field?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I'm not sure how I should attempt to deserialize some JSON that looks like this:

```js
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "stringColumn",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "DateColumn",
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "name": "NumberColumn",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "This is a string",
            1548091093000,
            123
        ]
    ]
}
```

The `columns` vector describes the types and number of entries inside an element of the `data` vector. The example above could be converted to CSV as such (ignoring the types):

```
stringColumn,DateColumn,NumberColumn
"This is a string",1548091093000,123
```

Some extra challenges:

1. A `number` can be an integer or a float. Should I represent it as an enum?
2. The large number `1548091093000` is the number of *milliseconds* since the UNIX epoch (equivalent to `Monday, January 21, 2019 5:18:13 PM`). Because I have dates (using epoch) and numbers, I cannot distinguish them easily without having access to the "header" description...
3. I'm using the [`restson`](https://crates.io/crates/restson) to call a REST API which returns the JSON above. restson will call `serde_json::from_str()` with the final type. This means this type must implement `Deserialize`.

How can I deserialize this?

Comment: "REST API which returns the JSON above", that not a rest api...

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Your data is completely, hopelessly dynamic, which means that you don't get to use any nice tools like deriving `Deserialize`.

You'll need to use [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.36/serde_json/enum.Value.html), an enum of all possible JSON types for the data. You can derive a struct for the fixed structure though:

```
use serde_derive; // 1.0.84
use serde_json::{self, Value}; // 1.0.34 

static INPUT: &str = r#"
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "stringColumn",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "DateColumn",
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "name": "NumberColumn",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "This is a string",
            1548091093000,
            123
        ]
    ]
}
"#;

#[derive(Debug, serde_derive::Deserialize)]
struct Thing {
    columns: Vec<Column>,
    data: Vec<Vec<Value>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, serde_derive::Deserialize)]
struct Column {
    name: String,
    r#type: String,
}

fn main() {
    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Thing>(INPUT);
    println!("{:#?}", data)
}
```

> A number can be an integer or a float

This is already handled by [`serde_json::Number`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.36/serde_json/struct.Number.html)

See also:

- [Can Serde deserialize JSON to one of a set of types depending on the value of a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53018165/155423)

Comment: Thanks, I've used a type alias `pub type DataValue = serde_json::Value;` and added a manual conversion function from `serde_json::Value` to a real `struct`.

Comment: @big_gie what do you mean by *"a manual conversion function [...] to a real struct"*? You don't know what number or kinds of data are coming in, so you cannot create a struct with fixed fields.

Comment: I know the structure of the received json. So for the above I have `struct Data { fields: Vec<DataField>, results: Vec<Vec<DataType>> }`. I have a function that takes the `serde_json::Value` and populate this struct by manually accessing the `serde_json::Value` fields.

Comment: @big_gie ah, right, `columns` is a fixed schema. I've updated to address that.